# Missing update statement in if statement makes infinite loop

Tags: java, if-statement, infinite-loop

Why does this code produce an infinite loop?

```
for(int i=0; i<10; ) {
  i = i++;
  System.out.println("Hello World!");
}
```

Comment: for what reason would you need to do this when you can just say (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)

Comment: This is infinite. You, every time, resetting i to 0 after each for iteration. YOu can test below code for understanding. ` for(int i=0; i<10; ) {
  i = i++;
  System.out.println(i);
}`

Comment: Because `i = i++;` should just be `i++;`. If you tried to do `for (int i=0; i<10; i = i++)` you would have the same problem, for reasons explained in the duplicate question.